# Hide seconds from datetime picker in front-end

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, datetimepicker

I am using datetimepicker to display date and time and store it in a particular model in this format `("2015-01-01T15:10:23")`, from this I want to hide seconds only in front-end, but not in back-end model.
Could anyone help me to solve my problem?

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.datetime.$invalid}">
  <label>date and time</label>
      <div class='col-sm-12 input-group date'>
         <input id="datetimeid" ng-model="datemodel" name="datetime" type='text' class="form-control" ng-change="datevalidator()" placeholder="date and time" required/>
</div>

$scope.datevalidator = function () {
var datetime = $scope.datemodel;
$scope.datemodel = (datetime.indexOf(':00') > -1) ? datetime.replace(':00',"") : datetime;
};
```

Comment: could you check if my answer was satisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular built-in filter:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Here you have more info on how to use it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date